# Python & ConfigParser

Tags: python, configparser

The following is from a Python script that calls a PS script on a remote machine.

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
import sys
import urllib.parse
import ps_sync
import ps_async
import ps_async2
import configparser
import json

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

# jsonifyで日本語を返却するための設定
app.config['JSON_AS_ASCII'] = False

# confファイルの読み込み
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('/opt/apps/current/cfg/connection.cfg', 'UTF-8')
config.read('/opt/apps/current/cfg/command.cfg', 'UTF-8')
config.read('/opt/apps/current/cfg/url.cfg', 'UTF-8')
validation = open('/opt/apps/current/cfg/prohibited_char.cfg')

# 禁則文字リスト生成
no_char_list = validation.read().split()

class vd_status_check(Resource):
    def get(self, tenant_id, collection_id):
        # 各テナント別に接続先を選定
        if tenant_id in ['tenant1']:
            hv_server = config['tenant1']['hv_server']
        elif tenant_id in ['tenant2']:
            hv_server = config['tenant']['hv_server']
        elif tenant_id in ['tenant3']:
            hv_server = config['tenant3']['hv_server']
        elif tenant_id in ['tenant4']:
            hv_server = config['tenant4']['hv_server']
        elif tenant_id in ['poc-vdi']:
            hv_server = config['general']['hv_server']
        elif tenant_id in ['NEWTENANT1']:
            hv_server = config['NEWTENANT1']['hv_server']
        elif tenant_id in ['NEWTENANT2']:
            hv_server = config['NEWTENANT2']['hv_server']
        elif tenant_id in ['NEWTENANT3']:
            hv_server = config['NEWTENANT3']['hv_server']
        elif tenant_id in ['NEWTENANT4']:
            hv_server = config['NEWTENANT4']['hv_server']
        else:
            return print('指定されたテナントが存在しません')

        # クエリストリング呼び出し
        state = request.args.get('state', None)

        # コレクションIDの加工(ダブルコート追加)
        collect_id = '\"' + collection_id + '\"'

        # コマンド実行パス読み出し
        cmd = config['cmd']['status_vds']


        # powershellを同期処理で呼び出し
        if state is None:
            result = ps_sync.invoke(rdcb_server,
                                    cmd,
                                    tenant_id,
                                    collect_id)
        else:
            result = ps_sync.invoke(rdcb_server,
                                    cmd,
                                    tenant_id,
                                    collect_id,
                                    state)

        # powershell実行結果(JSON)にcodeが含まれていればステータスコードも返却
        if 'code' in result:
            response = jsonify(result)
            response.status_code = result['code']
            return response
        # 通常のpowershell実行結果はJSONIFY不要
        return result
```

Now, the new tenants are on a different hypervisor and the path for this has already been set. The problem is that paths for the Powershell script for the old tenants is set in a block in a .cfg file. The path to the scripts on the new hypervisor will be slightly different, however. 
What would be an elegant way to alter this script so that it refers to another script for the new tenants than for the old ones?

```
[cmd]
status_vds:C:\\dir1\\script.ps1
...

[cmd2]
status_vds:C:\\dir2\\script.ps1
...
```

Shorter explanation:
1) Currently tenant1 - tenant4 will invoke the the command from

```
cmd = config['cmd']['status_vds']
```

[cmd] is a list of paths in file command.cfg

2) NEWTENANT1 - NEWTENANT4 is supposed to invoke the command from

```
cmd = config['cmd2']['status_vds']
```

[cmd2] is a list of paths in the same command.cfg

Comment: `return print('指定されたテナントが存在しません')` would return `None`.

Comment: If the tenant belongs to the "NEWTENANT" group, it should invoke the command from the block [CMD2] instead of [CMD1] in the configuration file command.cfg